# How to route ASP .NET Razor Pages with dynamic value in path before page?

Tags: asp.net-core, url-routing, razor-pages

I am using ASP .NET Core, Version 7.
On my web app, tenants will be assigned an ID.

I want all the URLs on the app to be of the form so that the tenant ID is in the URL right after the server address and before the path to the page:
http://serveraddress//PageName

Right now, I am using a query parameter, so it looks like:
https://localhost:7161/ReportIssue?TenantId=6ee0558e-f783-4d6d-8bf9-b439835b3ad8

I want it to look like this:
https://localhost:7161/6ee0558e-f783-4d6d-8bf9-b439835b3ad8/ReportIssue

How do I do this?

Comment: what have you tried?  Maybe something like: app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{TenantId?}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/");

Comment: I hadn't tried anything yet because I had no idea where to start.
I tried what you specified above (app.MapControllerRoute(name: "default", pattern: "{TenantId?}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");), but trying to use the URL yields a 404 error.

For example, this, I would have thought via the routing would have gone to the Index page?:
https://localhost:7161/6ee0558e-f783-4d6d-8bf9-b439835b3ad8

Comment: You're probably using default razor routing right now... which is basically folder/controller/queryvars...   Not sure if you can put a query var first... but routing is where you need to change things.  This will have effects across the board, so be sure you always have the tenantid available and that this has no security risks since you are passing what looks like an encoded value in a GET:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: Thanks. Took some reading, but I found custom routing on pages. Using '@page "~/{TenantId}" on each of the pages, and then passing TenantId to the page get and post methods did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used custom routing.
I added `@page "~/{TenantId}/"` to the top of the page, and then in the .cs file added `string TenantId` to the page methods for OnGet and OnPostAsync. The navigation controls in _layout were then broken, and the @Model.TenantId field seems to be populated only after the _layout controls are inserted. For now I am copying the layout controls into all the pages, unifying that can be tomorrow's problem. Also had to switch to using an href= instead of the asp-* attributes in the navigation anchor tags.

Comment: is sounds like your controllers/cshtml files are not in the "pages" folder, but in "wwwroot"? and/or maybe not added as razor pages to the project.

Answer (score 0):

The inefficient way to achieve this is to add a route template to each `@page` directive that contains a parameter representing the `tenantid`:

`@page "{tenantId}"`

But you have to remember to do this with every page you add to the application.

A more scalable solution is to create a custom `PageRouteModelConvention` (https://www.learnrazorpages.com/advanced/custom-route-conventions) that does this at start up to every page in the application. The following code demonstrates how to add an extra attribute route containing the `tenantId` parameter for all pages:

```
public class TenantPageRouteModelConvention : IPageRouteModelConvention
{
    public void Apply(PageRouteModel model)
    {
        foreach(var selector in model.Selectors.ToList())
        {
            var template = selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template;

            model.Selectors.Add(new SelectorModel()
            {
                AttributeRouteModel = new AttributeRouteModel
                {
                    Template = $"{{tenantId}}/{template}"
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

You register this `TenantPageRouteModelConvention` when you add Razor Pages to the services:

```
builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.Add(new TenantPageRouteModelConvention());
});
```

And that's it. All pages added to the application will automatically get the route that includes the `tenantId` parameter generated for them. You don't need to remember to add the route template to the individual pages.